# Shortcut for going to the trailing curly brace "}"

Tags: key-bindings

Is there a shortcut for going to the trailing curly brace in a long piece of code?

In a few editors if I double click the `{` it takes me to the trailing brace `}`.

While writing large pieces of code I seem to forget to add this at times and  also it would make debugging easy if such an implementation is available.

I know the shortcut for searching words, take the cursor on the word and press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>. Is there any similar shortcut for finding ending braces?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you looking for [`:h %`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%25)?

```
%           Find the next item in this line after or under the
            cursor and jump to its match. |inclusive| motion.
            Items can be:
            ([{}])      parenthesis or (curly/square) brackets
                    (this can be changed with the
                    'matchpairs' option)
```

Pressing <kbd>%</kbd> in normal mode when the cursor is before or on an item like a parenthesis will jump to the matching item.

Comment: There is also ":set showmatch" or ":set sm" in vi, but I kind of hate it because it jumps around so much. But it is another option.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was looking for thank you sir.. you've just made reviews a lot easier for me :)

Answer (score 2):

If your `{}` is on first column:

- `]]` goto next `{` in first column, it's the open `{` of next function.
- `][` goto next `}` in first column, it's the close `}` of current function.
- `[[` goto previous `{` in first column, it's the open `{` of current function.
- `[]` goto previous `}` in first column, it's the close `}` of previous function.

It doesn't care how many nested `{}` there are, it only looks for `{}` in first column.

You can also use `]}` and `[{` to goto `}` and `{` of current `{}` block.